# Remove specific session variable

Tags: php, session, get, session-variables

I save some session variables in my website by a form submit. With this form the customer can add multiple dimensions to his product. for Each submit the website displays the chosen dimensions. So there a sometimes multiple configurations visible.

The customer must be able to remove such configuration (thus a part of the SESSION).

With this piece of code I save the Configurations in the SESSION:

```
if(isset($_POST['wz_submit_saving_1'])) :

    $straight_saving = array(
        'wz_str_saving' => $_POST['wz_str_saving'],
        'wz_saving_a' => $_POST['wz_saving_a'],
        'wz_saving_b' => $_POST['wz_saving_b'],
        'wz_submit_saving_1' => $_POST['wz_submit_saving_1']
    );

    $_SESSION['straight_saving'][] = $straight_saving;

endif;
```

I show them and each configuration has a delete link:

```
<a class="remove_link" href="http://www.myurl.com/?wz_submit_saving_remove_1">Verwijder sparing</a>
```

With the following code I remove the session.

```
if(isset($_GET['wz_submit_saving_remove_1'])) :

    unset($_SESSION['straight_saving']);

endif;
```

But when I do this, all the Configurations in the SESSION $straight_saving; are gone. So I only need to delete the configuration out of the session on which remove button I click and not all of them.

Can someone tell me if I'm doing it the right way with the GET link or do I need to do something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our chat it was more clear:

You want to unset every saving you add accordingly after pushing it in your session:

```
foreach($_SESSION['straight_saving'] as $key => $saving) {
//You can create a link that says ?saving=$key
}
```

Than you can unset the right session after by doing `unset($_SESSION['straight_saving'][$_GET['saving']]`. Don't forget to put some checks in it that saves people from putting anything in the URL.

Comment: Yes, but how can I let correspond them with each other if understand what I mean.

Comment: What? I don't understand the question.

Comment: I see you're dutch. Ask your question in Dutch :)

Comment: Sorry voor het gebrekkig Engels. Hoe kan ik ervoor zorgen dat als ik de "remove" link van een bepaalde configuratie aan klik de corresponderende array uit de SESSION gehaald wordt.

Comment: Is afhankelijk van je strategie in principe. Wat je kunt doen is de GET anders opstellen: ?unset=denaamvandekey en dan `$_SESSION['straight_saving'][$_GET['unset']]`. edit: haakje vergeten

Comment: Het betreft deze pagina. Misschien begrijp je het concept dan beter: http://www.glasbestellen.nl/keukenwand-rechte-sparingen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41867/discussion-between-robbert-and-captaincarl)